# Is there a TRY_CONVERT_TIMEZONE in Snowflake? or some workaround

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, timestamp-with-timezone

I have 3 tables in snowflake DW as below with some sample data

**Txn table**

**txn_id    txn_date                acc_id**

T1     2022-04-01 00:02:04         A1

T2     2022-04-02 00:07:03         A2

T3     2022-04-03 00:08:04         A3

T4     2022-04-04 00:09:05         A4

T5     2022-04-05 00:12:06         A5

**Acc table**

**acc_id tz_id**

A1      TZ2

A2      TZ4

A3      TZ6

A4      TZ8

A5      TZ10

**Timezone table**

**tz_id         tz_desc           tz_cd        tz_long_name**

TZ2         US/Hawaii            HST         North America Hawaii

TZ4         Australia/Sydney     AEST        Australian Eastern

TZ6         BLABLABLA*******     XXX         System Generated

TZ8         #$#$%%@%             XXX         System Generated

TZ10        <>                   XXX         System Generated

**Things to note:**

1. Txn_date is in GMT field
2. Bad timezones exist in timezone table

I am looking for a built in function that converts txn_date which is in GMT field to it's account specific timezone, taking into account bad timezones, something like how TRY_CAST works.
If conversion fails, then it defaults to null.

There's a convert_timezone function of snowflake
SELECT convert_timezone('GMT', 'US/Hawaii', '2022-04-05 00:12:06')

but this breaks in the below case
SELECT convert_timezone('GMT', '<>', '2022-04-05 00:12:06')

**Final output**

**txn_id       txn_date             acc_id  tz_id        tz_desc             local_txn_date**

T1     2022-04-01 00:02:04         A1      TZ2         US/Hawaii          converted timestamp

T2     2022-04-02 00:07:03         A2      TZ4        Australia/Sydney    converted timestamp

T3     2022-04-03 00:08:04         A3      TZ6        BLABLABLA*******    NULL

T4     2022-04-04 00:09:05         A4      TZ8        #$#$%%@%            NULL

T5     2022-04-05 00:12:06         A5      TZ10       <>                  NULL

Comment: Have you looked at try_to_timestamp? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_timestamp.html

Comment: You can't put a timezone into try_to_timestamp. The problem here is that the `timezones` may be invalid rather than (or possibly in addition to) the timestamps being bad.

Answer (score 1):

While there is no built-in `try_convert_timezone` function, it's possible to solve this problem using a JavaScript UDF.

Rather than reinventing the convert_timezone function (and possibly getting subtly different results), the way to address this problem is to detect whether a timezone string is valid or not valid.

The following function accepts a string that may or may not be a valid timezone. JavaScript uses the same timezone strings as Snowflake that look like `America/New_York`. If the input string is a valid timezone string, it returns the same string. If it's an invalid timezone string, it catches an error in the attempt to use the string as a timezone and returns NULL.

The key thing about returning NULL is that for almost all Snowflake functions, specifying just one null input results in NULL for the output. So we can use the null output of this function to make the convert_timezone output null too.

First, create the UDF:

```
create or replace function VALIDATE_TIMEZONE(TZ string)
returns string
language javascript
strict immutable
as
$$
    // Snowflake does not support 3-letter timezones except for GMT/UTC
    if ("|GMT|UTC|EST|".indexOf("|" + TZ.toUpperCase() + "|") != -1) {
        return TZ.trim();
    }
    if (TZ.trim().length === 3) {
        return null
    }
    
    try {
        let t = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: TZ});
    } catch (e){
        if(e.message.substr(0, 27) == 'Invalid time zone specified'){
            return null
        } else {
            throw e.message;
        }          
    }
    return TZ;
$$;
```

Now, test the UDF on some sample inputs:

```
select validate_timezone('foo'); -- Returns NULL
select validate_timezone('America/New_York'); -- Returns America/New_York
```

Now see what happens when used inside the `convert_timezone` function:

```
-- Returns 2022-04-07 17:00:00.000
select convert_timezone( validate_timezone('GMT')
                        ,validate_timezone('America/New_York')
                        ,'2022-04-07 21:00:00'::timestamp_ntz);

-- Returns NULL
select convert_timezone( validate_timezone('GMT')
                        ,validate_timezone('blah-blah')
                        ,'2022-04-07 21:00:00'::timestamp_ntz);
```

Comment: Hi Greg, it doesn't work for all TZ names. Snowflake does not support the majority of timezone abbreviations(e.g. PDT, EST, etc.) https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/convert_timezone.html#usage-notes validate_timezone('PST') doesn't return NULL but convert_timezone fails to process it.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that, Gokhan. I added a check to the code that will return `null` for any three-letter timezone except the ones I noticed it supported, GMT, UTC, and EST.